# MySQL DB returns unpredictable Integer value on use of Exist condition. Sometimes it is Integer sometimes its BigInteger

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am running below mentioned query using JDBC: .

```
SELECT DISTINCT   
pd.ProductDefId,   
pd.ProductName,    
EXISTS (SELECT '1' FROM CachedButtons ct
         where ct.ProductId = pd.ProductId) as isSponsored 
From ProductData AS pd
```

I am catching the response in Integer variable for isSponsored value. But sometime I am getting an exception "java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer".

Comment: "I am catching the response in Integer variable": which variable name are talking about please  ? `isSponsored` ? or something else ?

Comment: it is isSponsored variable.

Comment: not sure about isSponsored. the `exists` function return either `true` or  `false` depending on whether a row is returned or not.

Comment: the return value of  an exist is neither a BigInt nor an Int rather a boolean

Comment: I changed the variable as Boolean and I am getting exception "java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean"

Comment: You might want to consider using a a [`case` construct](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case), at least as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please you check whether `ct.ProductId` and `pd.ProductId` share the same type ? one could be BigInteger and the other `Integer` , making the comparison on your `exists()` impossible because of casting problem.

Comment: Both the ids are integer.

Comment: if there are ok, it means the problem is in your (jdbc) code and not the database. can you post the code where you run the query and fetch the data ??